# Checkout CI commit id in CD pipeline, triggered by CI in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, cicd

I have a CI and CD pipeline - both .yaml files, running in Azure DevOps.

The CD pipeline is triggered when the CI pipeline completes:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: ci
      source: "MyProject - CI"
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main
            - develop
```

In the CD pipeline I should have access to the source code as well, which I can do by using the `Checkout` task.

However, this task always takes the latest version of the source, and not the source that was the trigger of the CI pipeline.

Is there any way to access the CI's commit id, and use that version to checkout?

Comment: I not sure but I believe that you cannot pass variables between pipeline resource triggers. If you use the same build agent (self hosted) for both pipelines, another approach would be to store into a file your CI commit ID and consume this information on the CD pipeline. Is there a way you use two pipelines instead of a build and release pipeline? You could get the commit ID on a release pipeline connected with the build pipeline

Comment: Please check the answer and the suggestions to see if it helpful to you. Then you can sign it as a correct one to benefit others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rest api and powershell in your build. As an example, you can use Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId to get comment info of previous build:

```
$token = "$(System.AccessToken)" 

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$orgUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
$teamProject = "$(System.TeamProject)"

$buildId = '$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)'

$restGetBuild = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds/$buildId`?api-version=6.0"

function InvokeGetRequest ($GetUrl)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}


$result = InvokeGetRequest $restGetBuild

$commit = $result.sourceVersion

& git checkout $commit
```